# Can’t kill a process that’s running—yet apparently not visible—in the task manager

Tags: process, kill, id

I started an application that won’t run, yet I can’t delete it cause it’s still running. I can print the PID, but not kill the process using it.

```
~ $ ps ax | grep snappr | awk '{print $1}'
70824
~ $ kill $(ps ax | grep snappr | awk '{print $1}')
-bash: kill: (70832) - No such process
```

Comment: @BeowulfOF: "Ordering of ps output"? Huh? How does that make sense? If `snappr` were running, the first command would have listed two PIDs: that of `snappr` and that of the `grep` -- as explained in my answer, which I posted half an hour _before_ you posted this comment. ... ... ... ... ... P.S. You might want to proofread your contributions a bit better ("I the error states", "ad", "mit").

Comment: Sorry Scott, the mistakes came from autocorrection, I wrote this in short from my mobile. No Excuse, thats why I deleted the comment.

Comment: Your `grep snappr` is matching the process `grep snappr`.

Comment: What platform? Mac OS X? Linux? Cygwin?

Answer (score 17):

Did you notice that you got two different PIDs in the two tries?

Consider this: if you type a command like `vi raven.txt`,
then `ps ax` will display a line that shows a command of `vi raven.txt`. 
Likewise, if you type a command like `grep snappr`,
then `ps ax` will display a line that shows a command of `grep snappr`. 
And, if you pipe the output of that `ps` through `grep snappr`,
the `grep` will find the line *that is describing itself*. 
So, if you type

```
$ ps ax | grep snappr | awk '{print $1}'
```

repeatedly, it will print a different number every time
(because it's printing the PID of `grep`,
and you get a new, unique `grep` process every time you run the command).

Finally, consider: the `kill` command cannot be executed until its argument(s) are known. 
For its argument to be known, the `$(ps ax | grep snappr | awk '{print $1}')` pipeline
must have completed.  This implies that the `grep` must have terminated<sup>1</sup>. 
Therefore, the `kill` is being given the PID of the `grep` process,
but only after the `grep` process has terminated --
so, naturally, it reports "No such process".

Perhaps I should have mentioned that there is no `snappr` process running. 
If there were, your first command would output two numbers: the PID of `snappr`,
and the PID of `grep snappr`. 
Now, if `snappr` were running, your command might start running semi-correctly,
by which I mean it does what you want but also gives an error message. 
If the `snappr` is running with PID 42097, and `grep snappr` runs with PID 70848,
then the `kill` command will be `kill 42097 70858`, which will kill the `snappr`
and get an error message from trying to kill the `grep` process that no longer exists.

You'll probably want to improve on this.  My favorite way, which I invented 20 years ago,
it to change the `grep` to `grep "[s]nappr"`, which will match `snappr` but will not match itself. 
Another approach is to use `pgrep` rather than `ps | grep`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Alternatively, the `awk` could finish if the `grep` merely closed its stdout. 
This would be very unusual behavior for a *nix program.

Comment: I have a bash script which I only want running once on my machine. Within the script I use this code to check (where $THIS is the name of the script): `PRIOR="$(ps --no-headers -Ao "pid,ppid,sid,args"|grep "$THIS"|grep -Ev "(grep |$PPID |$$ |<defunct>)")"`. If $PRIOR is not null then the script is already running. I've had more success with this than with `pgrep`.

Comment: Ah, yes, the old `grep | grep -v` solution. Why run an extra process that you don't need? Work smarter, not harder.

Comment: I agree it looks messy. I'd be happy to find a better, reliable, way. ps -C doesn't catch all processes, pgrep includes defunct processes.

Comment: (1) Do you know of any problem with my `grep "[s]nappr"` solution? (2) As long as we're talking about killing processes, who cares whether defunct processes are included? Killing a defunct process is a no-op.

Comment: I realise we are getting off-topic here. I like your [s]napper solution! But I need to exclude defuncts because I really want to know if there is a live process out there (in which case, stop now!) or just something that is dying. And I not only need to exclude the grep call I also need to exclude the running instance of the script itself ($$), and possibly the parent that called it ($PPID).

Comment: +1 for a good answer (but... invented the [x] trick 20 years ago? or just read about it in the Unix FAQ ? ;) )

Comment: I prefer this trick `ps ax | egrep "[ /](PID|${command})"` or `ps ax | grep "[ /]${command}"` to avoid the 3 times stupid `grep ${command} | grep -v grep`.

Answer (score 8):

#### Shorter Answer

Don’t jump through Bash hoops to kill `snappr` with `ps`, piped through `grep` and then piped through `awk` like that. Instead try to kill it like this using [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill); no muss or fuss and it targets based on process name out of the box:

```
sudo pkill snappr
```

#### Longer Answer

Not too clear with how [Snapper](http://snapper.io) operates on a system process level, but the issue could be that you are only grabbing the child process ID instead of the parent process ID.

In fact I believe the method you are using to grab a process ID (`ps ax | grep snappr | awk '{print $1}'`) would return a whole list of process IDs connected to `snappr` regardless of whether it is parent or child. So using that you *might* kill one process ID that is just a child process ID yet the parent ID would still be active and able to “spawn” another child process to compensate.

So perhaps you can do something like this to grab the definitive parent ID of whatever process ID you feed it and act on it; simple proof of concept of how it works:

```
ps -p [process ID] -o ppid=
```

Running that bare command in Bash will give you the parent process ID of the child process ID you put in `[process ID]`. So if the child ID `4567` has a parent process ID of `123` then the command would be:

```
ps -p 4567 -o ppid=
```

And that would return, `123`.

That said, this could be a dangerous way of dealing with a stray process since if your script grabs the actual parent process ID of `snapper`, then the parent of that process ID could really be your own Bash shell. So you might inadvertently just kill your Bash shell instead of the `snapper` knocking you off the system while leaving `snapper` process running.

But all that said, why not make your life easier and just run [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) like this:

```
sudo pkill snappr
```

That will kill all processes connected to `snappr` without any fancy command line juggling.

Comment: Of course, if you're trying to kill a process that you started (as stated in the question), as long as it isn't setuid, you own the process, and you don't need `sudo`. And you should not use `sudo` if you don't need to.

Comment: More likely - the process doesn't actually exist, `grep` is matching itself.

Comment: use `killall` instead of `pkill` since by default `pkill` overkills.